# Python recursive permutation program explanation

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a code that uses recursion to calculate the permutation of the characters of a string. I understand normal tail recursion and recursions for palindrome, factorial, decimal to binary conversion easily but i am having problem understanding how this recursion works, i mean how it actually works in the background, not just the abstract stuff from the higher level i get that.

here is the code

```
from __future__ import print_function

def permutef(s):
    #print('\nIM CALLED\n')
    out = []

    if len(s) == 1:
        out = [s]
    else:
        for i,let in enumerate(s):

            #print('LETTER IS {} index is {}'.format(let, i))

            #Slicing as not including that letter but includes every letter except that to perform the permutation

            for perm in permutef( s[:i] + s[i+1:] ):

                print(perm)

                out += [let + perm]
    return out


per = permutef('abc')

print('\n\n\n', per, '\n\n\n')
```

[image]

I was writing in a paper each circle is for each letter and how the corresponding stack pops

Don't ask about my handwriting i know its awesome (sarcasm)

here is the output screenshot

[image]

i want to understand the nitty gritty about how this works in the background, but i can't seem to fathom the concept, very very thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 1  def permutef(s):
 2      out = []
 3      if len(s) == 1:
 4          out = [s]
 5      else:
 6          for i,let in enumerate(s):
 7              for perm in permutef( s[:i] + s[i+1:] ):
 8                  print(perm)
 9                  out += [let + perm]
10      return out
```

The principle is fairly straightforward. A one-character string (line 3) only has one permutation, represented by a list containing that character (line 4). The permutations of longer strings are generated by taking each character in the string and permuting the remaining characters - a fairly classic recursive divide-and-conquer approach.

For problems like this the [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20permutef%28s%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20out%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20len%28s%29%20%3D%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20out%20%3D%20%5Bs%5D%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20i,let%20in%20enumerate%28s%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20perm%20in%20permutef%28%20s%5B%3Ai%5D%20%2B%20s%5Bi%2B1%3A%5D%20%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28perm%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20out%20%2B%3D%20%5Blet%20%2B%20perm%5D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20out%0A%0Aa%20%3D%20permutef%28'abc'%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=18&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) site can be useful to visualise the execution of your code. The link I've provided is pre-loaded with the code above, and you can step forwards and backwards through the code until you understand how it works.